# How to use sklearn.countvectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I tried to use sklearn.countvectorizer but it didn't work. I used a corpus with 2 sample lines (I intend to import wikipedia data later, but for now I need to get the system working):

```
__label__1 Buyer beware: This is a self-published book, and if you want to know why--read a few paragraphs! Those 5 star reviews must have been written by Ms. Haddon's family and friends--or perhaps, by herself! I can't imagine anyone reading the whole thing--I spent an evening with the book and a friend and we were in hysterics reading bits and pieces of it to one another. It is most definitely bad enough to be entered into some kind of a "worst book" contest.
__label__2 Glorious story: I loved Whisper of the wicked saints. The story was amazing and I was pleasantly surprised at the changes in the book. I am not normaly someone who is into romance novels, but the world was raving about this book and so I bought it. I loved it !
```

This is my code to create the world-level vectorizer:

```
# load the dataset
data = open('corpus.txt').read()
labels, texts = [], []
for i, line in enumerate(data.split("\n")):
    content = line.split()
    labels.append(content[0])
    texts.append(content[1:])

# create a dataframe using texts and lables
trainDF = pandas.DataFrame()
trainDF['text'] = texts
trainDF['label'] = labels

# split the dataset into training and validation datasets 
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(trainDF['text'], trainDF['label'])

# label encode the target variable 
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

# create a count vectorizer object 
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(trainDF['text'])

# transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
xtrain_count =  count_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_count =  count_vect.transform(valid_x)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Even when I convert the trainDF['text'] to string I get another error:

```
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.
```

What do I do?

Comment: join the texts: `texts.append( ' '.join( content[1:]))`

Comment: you don't want to use label encoder separately for the train and test set. That way your train/test labels will be different.

Answer (score 0):

lowercase=False

as an argument for CountVectorizer()